# Reproduce cosine similarity between text documents of R code in Python

Tags: python, r, hierarchical-clustering

I am trying to create clusters using Hierarchical clustering of the description column i.e CDESCR of this dataset. https://drive.google.com/open?id=18c82RFffg_3ZoRJubQvq6oOjk1Q9Slai

I have the following code in R though which I can successfully create clusters, but I want to do the same analysis in Python.

R-code:

```
test <- data$CDESCR
test.corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(test))
test.dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(test.corpus)
test.dtm2 <- removeSparseTerms(test.dtm, sparse=0.95)
Dist.tdm <- test.dtm2
lsa.space = lsa(Dist.tdm, dimcalc_share())
lsa.textdoc = as.textmatrix(lsa.space)
cos.similarity = as.data.frame(cosine(lsa.textdoc))
DistSum.df.scale <- scale(cos.similarity)
d <- dist(DistSum.df.scale, method = "euclidean")
d <- replace(d, is.na(d), 0)
fit_Death <- hclust(d, method="ward.D2")
groups_death <- cutree(fit_Death, k=8) # cut tree into 8 clusters
clusters_death <- as.data.frame(groups_death)
```

Till now, in Python I have done following:
tokenizer here is a simple tokenizer to remove punctuation and other noise in the data

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=2, 
max_features=1000,tokenizer=tokenizer, ngram_range=(1,1))
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(list(data['CDESCR']))

svd = TruncatedSVD(117)
normalizer = Normalizer(copy=False)
lsa = make_pipeline(svd, normalizer)

X = lsa.fit_transform(X)

from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import linear_kernel
dist = linear_kernel(X,X)

from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import ward, dendrogram, cut_tree

linkage_matrix = ward(dist)
num_clusters=8
cutree = cut_tree(linkage_matrix, n_clusters=num_clusters)
```

But, I am not getting the same results.
I think I am not able to reproduce the code of R from scaling of cosine similarity.
I would appreciate it if anyone could help me out.